# Value Error trying to fit a neural network classifier using GridSearchCV

Tags: pandas, numpy, neural-network, classification, grid-search

I am trying to use GridSearchCV along with MLPClassifier in order to fit some training data using best parameters:

```
parameters={
    'learning_rate': ["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"],
    'hidden_layer_sizes': [x for x in itertools.product((10,20,30,40,50,100),repeat=3)],
    'alpha': [10.0 **-np.arange(1, 7)],
    'activation': ["logistic", "relu", "Tanh"]
    }
ord_pred = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (100,1))
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=ord_pred,param_grid=parameters,n_jobs=-1,verbose = 10)
    orders_prior1 = orders_prior.groupby('product_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3).fillna(0)
clf.fit(orders_prior1[['user_id','order_number','order_dow','order_hour_of_day','days_since_prior_order']]\
                      ,orders_prior1['product_id'], orders_prior1['user_order'])
```

However I got the following errors/exceptions:

```
   if self.alpha < 0.0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TransportableException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    681                 if 'timeout' in getfullargspec(job.get).args:
--> 682                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    683                 else:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
    645 

TransportableException: TransportableException
___________________________________________________________________________
ValueError                                         Wed Aug 16 19:23:55 2017
PID: 18804                            Python 3.6.2: C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
...........................................................................
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self=<sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel.BatchedCalls object>)
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
    127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        self.items = [(<function _fit_and_score>, (MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
       alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False),           user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

[32433710 rows x 5 columns], 0             196
1           14084
2           ...
Name: product_id, Length: 32433710, dtype: int64, <function _passthrough_scorer>, memmap([    1606,     1610,     1618, ..., 32433707, 32433708, 32433709]), memmap([       0,        1,        2, ..., 32190332, 32190334, 32190356]), 10, {'activation': 'logistic', 'alpha': array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.0...0000000e-04,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-06]), 'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 10, 10), 'learning_rate': 'constant'}), {'error_score': 'raise', 'fit_params': {}, 'return_n_test_samples': True, 'return_parameters': True, 'return_times': True, 'return_train_score': True})]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):
    134         return self._size
    135 

...........................................................................
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0=<list_iterator object>)
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
    127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
        func = <function _fit_and_score>
        args = (MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
       alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False),           user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

[32433710 rows x 5 columns], 0             196
1           14084
2           ...
Name: product_id, Length: 32433710, dtype: int64, <function _passthrough_scorer>, memmap([    1606,     1610,     1618, ..., 32433707, 32433708, 32433709]), memmap([       0,        1,        2, ..., 32190332, 32190334, 32190356]), 10, {'activation': 'logistic', 'alpha': array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.0...0000000e-04,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-06]), 'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 10, 10), 'learning_rate': 'constant'})
        kwargs = {'error_score': 'raise', 'fit_params': {}, 'return_n_test_samples': True, 'return_parameters': True, 'return_times': True, 'return_train_score': True}
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):
    134         return self._size
    135 

...........................................................................
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator=MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
       alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False), X=          user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

[32433710 rows x 5 columns], y=0             196
1           14084
2           ...
Name: product_id, Length: 32433710, dtype: int64, scorer=<function _passthrough_scorer>, train=memmap([    1606,     1610,     1618, ..., 32433707, 32433708, 32433709]), test=memmap([       0,        1,        2, ..., 32190332, 32190334, 32190356]), verbose=10, parameters={'activation': 'logistic', 'alpha': array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.0...0000000e-04,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-06]), 'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 10, 10), 'learning_rate': 'constant'}, fit_params={}, return_train_score=True, return_parameters=True, return_n_test_samples=True, return_times=True, error_score='raise')
    233 
    234     try:
    235         if y_train is None:
    236             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    237         else:
--> 238             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
        estimator.fit = <bound method BaseMultilayerPerceptron.fit of ML...n_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False)>
        X_train =           user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

[21606079 rows x 5 columns]
        y_train = 1606        17762
1610        17762
1618        ...
Name: product_id, Length: 21606079, dtype: int64
        fit_params = {}
    239 
    240     except Exception as e:
    241         # Note fit time as time until error
    242         fit_time = time.time() - start_time

...........................................................................
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in fit(self=MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
       alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False), X=          user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

[21606079 rows x 5 columns], y=1606        17762
1610        17762
1618        ...
Name: product_id, Length: 21606079, dtype: int64)
    613 
    614         Returns
    615         -------
    616         self : returns a trained MLP model.
    617         """
--> 618         return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)
        self._fit = <bound method BaseMultilayerPerceptron._fit of M...n_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False)>
        X =           user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

[21606079 rows x 5 columns]
        y = 1606        17762
1610        17762
1618        ...
Name: product_id, Length: 21606079, dtype: int64
    619 
    620     @property
    621     def partial_fit(self):
    622         """Fit the model to data matrix X and target y.

...........................................................................
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in _fit(self=MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
       alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False), X=          user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

[21606079 rows x 5 columns], y=1606        17762
1610        17762
1618        ...
Name: product_id, Length: 21606079, dtype: int64, incremental=False)
    320         if not hasattr(hidden_layer_sizes, "__iter__"):
    321             hidden_layer_sizes = [hidden_layer_sizes]
    322         hidden_layer_sizes = list(hidden_layer_sizes)
    323 
    324         # Validate input parameters.
--> 325         self._validate_hyperparameters()
        self._validate_hyperparameters = <bound method BaseMultilayerPerceptron._validate...n_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False)>
    326         if np.any(np.array(hidden_layer_sizes) <= 0):
    327             raise ValueError("hidden_layer_sizes must be > 0, got %s." %
    328                              hidden_layer_sizes)
    329 

...........................................................................
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in _validate_hyperparameters(self=MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
       alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False))
    386         if not isinstance(self.shuffle, bool):
    387             raise ValueError("shuffle must be either True or False, got %s." %
    388                              self.shuffle)
    389         if self.max_iter <= 0:
    390             raise ValueError("max_iter must be > 0, got %s." % self.max_iter)
--> 391         if self.alpha < 0.0:
        self.alpha = array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.0...0000000e-04,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-06])
    392             raise ValueError("alpha must be >= 0, got %s." % self.alpha)
    393         if (self.learning_rate in ["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"] and
    394                 self.learning_rate_init <= 0.0):
    395             raise ValueError("learning_rate_init must be > 0, got %s." %

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
___________________________________________________________________________

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

JoblibValueError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-7c1268d1d451> in <module>()
      9 orders_prior1 = orders_prior.groupby('product_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3).fillna(0)
     10 # up = orders_prior['product_id'].unique()
---> 11 clf.fit(orders_prior1                      [['user_id','order_number','order_dow','order_hour_of_day','days_since_prior_order']]                      ,orders_prior1['product_id'], orders_prior1['user_order'])
     12 
     13 # ord_pred.partial_fit(orders_prior.fillna(0).iloc[0:894]\

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups)
    943             train/test set.
    944         """
--> 945         return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    946 
    947 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _fit(self, X, y, groups, parameter_iterable)
    562                                   return_times=True, return_parameters=True,
    563                                   error_score=self.error_score)
--> 564           for parameters in parameter_iterable
    565           for train, test in cv_iter)
    566 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    766                 # consumption.
    767                 self._iterating = False
--> 768             self.retrieve()
    769             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    770             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    717                     ensure_ready = self._managed_backend
    718                     backend.abort_everything(ensure_ready=ensure_ready)
--> 719                 raise exception
    720 
    721     def __call__(self, iterable):

JoblibValueError: JoblibValueError
___________________________________________________________________________
Multiprocessing exception:
...........................................................................
C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py in _run_module_as_main(mod_name='ipykernel_launcher', alter_argv=1)
    188         sys.exit(msg)
    189     main_globals = sys.modules["__main__"].__dict__
    190     if alter_argv:
    191         sys.argv[0] = mod_spec.origin
    192     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
--> 193                      "__main__", mod_spec)
        mod_spec = ModuleSpec(name='ipykernel_launcher', loader=<_f...nda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel_launcher.py')
    194 
    195 def run_module(mod_name, init_globals=None,
    196                run_name=None, alter_sys=False):
    197     """Execute a module's code without importing it

    F:\thecads_vm-master\eds\Final Project\Instacart\<ipython-input-20-7c1268d1d451> in <module>()
          6 }
          7 ord_pred = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (100,1))
          8 clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=ord_pred,param_grid=parameters,n_jobs=-1,verbose = 10)
          9 orders_prior1 = orders_prior.groupby('product_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3).fillna(0)
         10 # up = orders_prior['product_id'].unique()
    ---> 11 clf.fit(orders_prior1                      [['user_id','order_number','order_dow','order_hour_of_day','days_since_prior_order']]                      ,orders_prior1['product_id'], orders_prior1['user_order'])
         12 
         13 # ord_pred.partial_fit(orders_prior.fillna(0).iloc[0:894]\
         14 #                      [['user_id','order_number','order_dow','order_hour_of_day','days_since_prior_order']]\
         15 #                      ,orders_prior.iloc[0:894]['product_id'], up)

    ...........................................................................
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self=GridSearchCV(cv=None, error_score='raise',
         ...rain_score=True,
           scoring=None, verbose=10), X=          user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [32433710 rows x 5 columns], y=0             196
    1           14084
    2           ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 32433710, dtype: int64, groups=0                 11
    1                 11
    2     ...Name: user_order, Length: 32433710, dtype: object)
        940 
        941         groups : array-like, with shape (n_samples,), optional
        942             Group labels for the samples used while splitting the dataset into
        943             train/test set.
        944         """
    --> 945         return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
            self._fit = <bound method BaseSearchCV._fit of GridSearchCV(...ain_score=True,
           scoring=None, verbose=10)>
            X =           user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [32433710 rows x 5 columns]
            y = 0             196
    1           14084
    2           ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 32433710, dtype: int64
            groups = 0                 11
    1                 11
    2     ...Name: user_order, Length: 32433710, dtype: object
            self.param_grid = {'activation': ['logistic', 'relu', 'Tanh'], 'alpha': [array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.0...0000000e-04,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-06])], 'hidden_layer_sizes': [(10, 10, 10), (10, 10, 20), (10, 10, 30), (10, 10, 40), (10, 10, 50), (10, 10, 100), (10, 20, 10), (10, 20, 20), (10, 20, 30), (10, 20, 40), (10, 20, 50), (10, 20, 100), (10, 30, 10), (10, 30, 20), (10, 30, 30), (10, 30, 40), (10, 30, 50), (10, 30, 100), (10, 40, 10), (10, 40, 20), ...], 'learning_rate': ['constant', 'invscaling', 'adaptive']}
        946 
        947 
        948 class RandomizedSearchCV(BaseSearchCV):
        949     """Randomized search on hyper parameters.

    ...........................................................................
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _fit(self=GridSearchCV(cv=None, error_score='raise',
         ...rain_score=True,
           scoring=None, verbose=10), X=          user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [32433710 rows x 5 columns], y=0             196
    1           14084
    2           ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 32433710, dtype: int64, groups=0                 11
    1                 11
    2     ...Name: user_order, Length: 32433710, dtype: object, parameter_iterable=<sklearn.model_selection._search.ParameterGrid object>)
        559                                   fit_params=self.fit_params,
        560                                   return_train_score=self.return_train_score,
        561                                   return_n_test_samples=True,
        562                                   return_times=True, return_parameters=True,
        563                                   error_score=self.error_score)
    --> 564           for parameters in parameter_iterable
            parameters = undefined
            parameter_iterable = <sklearn.model_selection._search.ParameterGrid object>
        565           for train, test in cv_iter)
        566 
        567         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train score info
        568         if self.return_train_score:

    ...........................................................................
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self=Parallel(n_jobs=-1), iterable=<generator object BaseSearchCV._fit.<locals>.<genexpr>>)
        763             if pre_dispatch == "all" or n_jobs == 1:
        764                 # The iterable was consumed all at once by the above for loop.
        765                 # No need to wait for async callbacks to trigger to
        766                 # consumption.
        767                 self._iterating = False
    --> 768             self.retrieve()
            self.retrieve = <bound method Parallel.retrieve of Parallel(n_jobs=-1)>
        769             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
        770             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time
        771             self._print('Done %3i out of %3i | elapsed: %s finished',
        772                         (len(self._output), len(self._output),

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sub-process traceback:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                         Wed Aug 16 19:23:55 2017
    PID: 18804                            Python 3.6.2: C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
    ...........................................................................
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self=<sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel.BatchedCalls object>)
        126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
        127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
        128         self._size = len(self.items)
        129 
        130     def __call__(self):
    --> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
            self.items = [(<function _fit_and_score>, (MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
           alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False),           user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [32433710 rows x 5 columns], 0             196
    1           14084
    2           ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 32433710, dtype: int64, <function _passthrough_scorer>, memmap([    1606,     1610,     1618, ..., 32433707, 32433708, 32433709]), memmap([       0,        1,        2, ..., 32190332, 32190334, 32190356]), 10, {'activation': 'logistic', 'alpha': array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.0...0000000e-04,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-06]), 'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 10, 10), 'learning_rate': 'constant'}), {'error_score': 'raise', 'fit_params': {}, 'return_n_test_samples': True, 'return_parameters': True, 'return_times': True, 'return_train_score': True})]
        132 
        133     def __len__(self):
        134         return self._size
        135 

    ...........................................................................
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0=<list_iterator object>)
        126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
        127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
        128         self._size = len(self.items)
        129 
        130     def __call__(self):
    --> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
            func = <function _fit_and_score>
            args = (MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
           alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False),           user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [32433710 rows x 5 columns], 0             196
    1           14084
    2           ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 32433710, dtype: int64, <function _passthrough_scorer>, memmap([    1606,     1610,     1618, ..., 32433707, 32433708, 32433709]), memmap([       0,        1,        2, ..., 32190332, 32190334, 32190356]), 10, {'activation': 'logistic', 'alpha': array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.0...0000000e-04,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-06]), 'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 10, 10), 'learning_rate': 'constant'})
            kwargs = {'error_score': 'raise', 'fit_params': {}, 'return_n_test_samples': True, 'return_parameters': True, 'return_times': True, 'return_train_score': True}
        132 
        133     def __len__(self):
        134         return self._size
        135 

    ...........................................................................
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator=MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
           alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False), X=          user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [32433710 rows x 5 columns], y=0             196
    1           14084
    2           ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 32433710, dtype: int64, scorer=<function _passthrough_scorer>, train=memmap([    1606,     1610,     1618, ..., 32433707, 32433708, 32433709]), test=memmap([       0,        1,        2, ..., 32190332, 32190334, 32190356]), verbose=10, parameters={'activation': 'logistic', 'alpha': array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.0...0000000e-04,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-06]), 'hidden_layer_sizes': (10, 10, 10), 'learning_rate': 'constant'}, fit_params={}, return_train_score=True, return_parameters=True, return_n_test_samples=True, return_times=True, error_score='raise')
        233 
        234     try:
        235         if y_train is None:
        236             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
        237         else:
    --> 238             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
            estimator.fit = <bound method BaseMultilayerPerceptron.fit of ML...n_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False)>
            X_train =           user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [21606079 rows x 5 columns]
            y_train = 1606        17762
    1610        17762
    1618        ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 21606079, dtype: int64
            fit_params = {}
        239 
        240     except Exception as e:
        241         # Note fit time as time until error
        242         fit_time = time.time() - start_time

    ...........................................................................
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in fit(self=MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
           alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False), X=          user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [21606079 rows x 5 columns], y=1606        17762
    1610        17762
    1618        ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 21606079, dtype: int64)
        613 
        614         Returns
        615         -------
        616         self : returns a trained MLP model.
        617         """
    --> 618         return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)
            self._fit = <bound method BaseMultilayerPerceptron._fit of M...n_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False)>
            X =           user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [21606079 rows x 5 columns]
            y = 1606        17762
    1610        17762
    1618        ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 21606079, dtype: int64
        619 
        620     @property
        621     def partial_fit(self):
        622         """Fit the model to data matrix X and target y.

    ...........................................................................
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in _fit(self=MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
           alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False), X=          user_id  order_number  order_dow  orde...               7.0  

    [21606079 rows x 5 columns], y=1606        17762
    1610        17762
    1618        ...
    Name: product_id, Length: 21606079, dtype: int64, incremental=False)
        320         if not hasattr(hidden_layer_sizes, "__iter__"):
        321             hidden_layer_sizes = [hidden_layer_sizes]
        322         hidden_layer_sizes = list(hidden_layer_sizes)
        323 
        324         # Validate input parameters.
    --> 325         self._validate_hyperparameters()
            self._validate_hyperparameters = <bound method BaseMultilayerPerceptron._validate...n_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False)>
        326         if np.any(np.array(hidden_layer_sizes) <= 0):
        327             raise ValueError("hidden_layer_sizes must be > 0, got %s." %
        328                              hidden_layer_sizes)
        329 

    ...........................................................................
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in _validate_hyperparameters(self=MLPClassifier(activation='logistic',
           alph...on_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False))
        386         if not isinstance(self.shuffle, bool):
        387             raise ValueError("shuffle must be either True or False, got %s." %
        388                              self.shuffle)
        389         if self.max_iter <= 0:
        390             raise ValueError("max_iter must be > 0, got %s." % self.max_iter)
    --> 391         if self.alpha < 0.0:
            self.alpha = array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.0...0000000e-04,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-06])
        392             raise ValueError("alpha must be >= 0, got %s." % self.alpha)
        393         if (self.learning_rate in ["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"] and
        394                 self.learning_rate_init <= 0.0):
        395             raise ValueError("learning_rate_init must be > 0, got %s." %

    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It is hard to detect the real cause of this and this runs for a very long time.  maybe it is something to do with the range of the alpha parameter search or something else. How to fix? Thanks.

Comment: When you do clf.fit you need to have two inputs: X and y (features and targets respectively). In your code you have 3 inputs.

Comment: the third is groups: array-like, with shape (n_samples,), optional
    Group labels for the samples used while splitting the dataset into
    train/test set.

Comment: Aren't orders_prior1['product_id'] supposed to be the groups?

Comment: This is the target parameter. I want to predict what the user will buy on his next order and at the same time want the split to be per each user and his order number as to not have a different product from the same user and order number in a different split.

Comment: I had the same exact error as you. I what got it to work for me was changing the alpha value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `'alpha': [10.0 **-np.arange(1, 7)]` to  `'alpha': 10.0 **-np.arange(1, 7)`
As you can see in the documentation of [np.arrange()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) the function itself already returns an array. Closing it in brackets (making it an array inside an array) causes GridSearch() to throw an exception.